# Why are my variables returning NaN after using .toString()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script in Google Sheets so I could add time without having to have two different columns for "hours" and "minutes". An example of a cell would be like this:

2 hrs 30 mins

The value1 parameter/argument would be this:

`[["foo"], ["bar"]]`

So, in effect, to call on the strings inside value1 would be like this: `value1[0/1][0]`

I would add a couple of cells in that format with code like this:

```js
var hrs;
var mins;
var time;
var arrayMins = [];

function ADDTIME(value1) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(value1);
  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    hrs += parseFloat(value1[i][0]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    arrayMins.push(value1[i][0].charAt(7) + value1[i][0].charAt(8));
  }
  for (j = 0; j < arrayMins.length; j++) {
    mins += parseInt(arrayMins[j]);
  }
  hrs += Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins -= mins / 60;
  var time = hrs.toString() + " hrs " + mins.toString() + " mins";
  return time;
}
```

The output of all that code is: NaN hrs NaN mins

I'm trying to output the answers in a format like this: 9 hrs 06 mins. I don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: Hi @BraylanBB121 - are you sure values where actually set correctly to start with  ... e.g. has the parseFloat/Int given a non-NaN value??

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `value1` in your situation?

Comment: Yes, Tanake is right. The value of the variable value1 should be included in the question above. Please edit your question and include an example of value of the function parameter for clarity. Based on your code above, looks like you are trying to perform math operations on strings or characters, which results to NaN.

Comment: And unless you are going to use the variables hrs, mins, time and arrayMins as global variables, declaring them outside the ADDTIME function is not a good idea. You may need to move them inside the function or set them as parameters if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by the fact you haven't initialized the variables at the top so attempting to "add" to undefined makes it NaN. Here's a quick proof of concept I got running by feeding in some dummy data (typeof and console.log are your friends)

```js
var hrs = 0;
var hrsNonInit;
var mins = 0;
var time;
var arrayMins = [];

function ADDTIME(value1) {
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var range = sheet.getRange(value1);
  var range = value1.length;
  
  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    hrs += parseFloat(value1[i][0]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    arrayMins.push(value1[i][0].charAt(7) + value1[i][0].charAt(8));
  }

  for (j = 0; j < arrayMins.length; j++) {
    mins += parseInt(arrayMins[j]);
  }

  hrs += Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins -= mins / 60;
  var time = hrs.toString() + " hrs " + mins.toString() + " mins";
  return time;
}

//Executable proof this is the problem
function usingNonInitVars(value1){
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var range = sheet.getRange(value1);
  var range = value1.length;
  
  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    hrsNonInit += parseFloat(value1[i][0]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
    arrayMins.push(value1[i][0].charAt(7) + value1[i][0].charAt(8));
  }

  for (j = 0; j < arrayMins.length; j++) {
    mins += parseInt(arrayMins[j]);
  }

  hrsNonInit += Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins -= mins / 60;
  var time = hrsNonInit.toString() + " hrs " + mins.toString() + " mins";
  return time;
}

var sampleData = [['5445464564564', '5445464564564'],['5445464564564', '5445464564564']]

console.log('with initialized hrs: ', ADDTIME(sampleData));
console.log('with non-initialized hrs: ', usingNonInitVars(sampleData))
```

Comment: In Javascript, you do not have to bind a value to a variable to properly initialize it, so your assumptions above are incorrect. Please remove your post or edit to for other users who might visit this question in the future.

Comment: Edited it. Feel free to actually run the code this time

Comment: Yes. But your description above still implies that variables should contain values in order to be properly initialized, which is not true. And declaring variables globally or on a global scope, specially with generic names such as the above (hrs, hrsNonInit min  etc), is generally not a good idea unless you actually intend to use them globally. You have to make sure that they do not collide with other global variables, which might be using the same name or ID. Our goal here is not to just solve problems, but to actually solve them correctly without causing further issues in the future.